# AJAX, JSON Object 404

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I've been trying to get my AJAX to work for a few days now and I don't understand why it won't work. It doesn't alert anything out and gives me an error of: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - [object%20Object]` it also keep returning everything NULL, JS, PHP. Not sure why.

**JS**

```
var fullName = ["John Doe", "Jane Doe"];

$(window).load(function(){
    getList();
});

function getList(){
    $.getJSON({
       type: "GET", /* the request's method: */
       url:"/names.php",    /* the request's location: */
       data: JSON.stringify({names: fullName}), /* the request's fields: */
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  /* the request's content-type : */
       dataType:"json", /* the response's content-type: */
       success: function(json){ /* the callback function */
         if(json.length > 0){
             $.each(json, function(i, v){
                console.info(v);
             });
          }
          else {
             alert('wtf?!');
          }
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$req=array_merge($_GET, $_POST);

$names=json_decode($req['names'], true);
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf8;');
echo json_encode($names);
```

Comment: Don't JSON.stringify the data! jQuery will do that for you.

Comment: Just to be sure, that PHP file is located at `http://yourdomain.com/names.php`, right?

Comment: `$.getJSON()` does not take an object argument. Please read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). Also, you know PHP has a `$_REQUEST` super global, right?

Comment: @Kolink Yeah it's linked correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `$.ajax` instead of `getJSON`. jQuery is thinking the whole configuration object is the URL!

Also, when you change it to `.ajax`, you don't have to `JSON.stringify` the data, that will be done automatically. So the code should be:

```
function getList(){
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET", /* the request's method: */
       url:"/names.php",    /* the request's location: */
       data: {names: fullName}, /* the request's fields: */
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  /* the request's content-type : */
       dataType:"json", /* the response's content-type: */
       success: function(json){ /* the callback function */
         if(json.length > 0){
             $.each(json, function(i, v){
                console.info(v);
             });
         } else {
            alert('wtf?!');
         }
       }
    });
}
```

A shorter version using with getJSON could be:

```
function getList(){
    $.getJSON("/names.php", {names: fullName}, function(json){ 
         if(json.length > 0){
             $.each(json, function(i, v){
                console.info(v);
             });
         } else {
             alert('wtf?!');
         }
    });
}
```

But then the requests would not be sent as JSON (only the response is expected to be JSON). So you'd need a slight change on your PHP:

```php
<?php
$names=$_GET['names'];
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf8;');
echo json_encode($names);
```

Comment: I actually didn't know the name mattered and thought it was fully editable.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee The *name* of what?

Comment: @Phil, I noticed your comment on the question while I was writing this answer, meaning you posted the actual reason before I did. If you want to add your own answer, I'll delete mine okay?

Comment: @Phil the name of the ajax function. This is all still showing up Null in my php file though and not returning anything to my ajax call.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee So it's getting to your PHP now, right? What is `var_dump($_GET)` giving?

Comment: It seems to come back to my ajax now but my PHP page is still telling me NULL, the json_encode() and var_dump()

Comment: It also only works with getJSON for some reason or another. ajax won't return anything to my dev console. Still shows null for some unknown reason in my PHP file.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Both work on my tests: http://jsfiddle.net/Hdsn5/. At least the requests are sent properly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25736/discussion-between-howdy-mcgee-and-bfavaretto)

Answer (score 0):

change `.getJSON` in your code to `.ajax` and the rest shoud work provided the path in URL is corret.

[API DOCMENTATION](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

From [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), jQuery.getJSON is a shorthand of:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: success
});
```

So you should use this way:

```
$.getJSON('/names.php', {names: fullName}, 
    function(data) {...}
);
```